# How do I output my Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>?

Tags: c#, dictionary, lookup, containskey, trygetvalue

I'm really stuck here now with my Dictionary Output:

I have this Code to "fill" the dictionary (basically there are 2 of them):

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> newDictionary = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, string>>();

Form1 _form1Object = new Form1();

foreach (SectionData section  in data.Sections) {
    var keyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();                  

    foreach (KeyData key in section.Keys)
        keyDictionary.Add(key.KeyName.ToString(), key.Value.ToString());

    newDictionary.Add(section.SectionName.ToString(), keyDictionary);
}
```

This works pretty well, but now I would like to search through it. That means I have a String which stores a "selection" from the "combobox" in Form1.class I have.

Now I want to lookup that String in my Dictionary, for that I have the following:

```
while (_form1Object.comboBox2.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
     _form1Object.SelectedItemName = _form1Object.comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();

     if (newDictionary.ContainsKey(_form1Object.SelectedItemName))
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", newDictionary[_form1Object.SelectedItemName]);
         Console.WriteLine("Dictionary includes 'SelectedItem' but there is no output");
     }
     else Console.WriteLine("Couldn't check Selected Name");
}
```

But, yes you're right, it doesn't work, the output in the console is:

> ```
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]
> ```

And I even don't get any of my `Console.WriteLine("Couln't check selected Name")` So that mean it will run through the IF statement but the Console.WriteLine function is not working.

Now my question, how do I lookup my String SelectedItemName in the `Dictionary<string,  Dictionary<string,string>>`?

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: It is working; the value of a key in the outer dictionary is another dictionary object, and `ToString()` on a dictionary uses the default behavior from `System.Object`: print out the name of the object's type.

Comment: `while (_form1Object.comboBox2.SelectedIndex > -1)` ????

Comment: This while checks if the user has selected something in the Combobox, if yes, it will go through the content of the while loop, or am I wrong?

Comment: I suppose newDictionary[_form1Object.SelectedItemName] returns your keyDictionary you filled before. You have to add the second index of your actual key newDictionary[_form1Object.SelectedItemName][index]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to implement your own output logic. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not override `Object.ToString` so the output is just the class name. Something like:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{ 
  public static string WriteContent(this Dictionary<string, string> source)
  {
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var kvp in source) {
      sb.AddLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
  }
}
```

Will allow you to just call `.WriteContent()` on `newDictionary[_form1object.SelectedItemName]` when that namespace is referenced.

Answer (score 2):

You need something similar to:

```
foreach (var keyValue in newDictionary[_form1Object.SelectedItemName])
{
   Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is working as it should work. Look you are fetching this expression

```
newDictionary[_form1Object.SelectedItemName]
```

where `newDictionary` has a string key and another dictionary as the value. So this expression will return you the `value` field of the parent dictionary which is actually a `dictionary`.

That means you also have to iterate over your child dictionary like this

```
 if (newDictionary.ContainsKey(_form1Object.SelectedItemName))
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Parent Key : {0}",_form1Object.SelectedItemName)
     foreach(var childDict in newDictionary[_form1Object.SelectedItemName])
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", childDict.Key,childDict.Value);
     }
 }
```